# What are the solutions of the Laplace equations for two (or more) eccentric cylinders?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem, bessel-functions

I am looking for solutions to Laplace equation for two eccentric cylinders in 3D with arbitrary boundary conditions. The boundary condtions also depend on the axial variable.

I tried to work with Bessel-function solutions in cylindrical coordiantes for each of the cylinder separately and merge them at the boundary by expanding the solutions for one of the cylinder in terms of the Bessel functions in the other coordinate system (centered on the interior cylinder). Unfortunately, when evaluting numerically this produces numerical problems due to singularity for r=0.

I read about the bipolar cylindrical coordinates, but I could not find the solution for my specific three-dimensional problem. My ultimate goal would be to generalise the solution for more than one inner circle.

How can I approach the problem?

[image]

Comment: Conformal mapping is a place to look.

Comment: Thank you. @Dr.MV do you have any pointers where to start?

Comment: from what I understand, conformal mapping can be used to solve laplace equation in 2D but not 3D.

Comment: Does the problem of interest have any dependence on the axial variable?  Is it not a 2-D problem then?

Comment: Try this paper. "Bipolar coordinates,image method and the method of fundamental solutions for Green’s functions of Laplace problems containing circular boundaries" at http://msvlab.hre.ntou.edu.tw/paper/new/EABE_2384.PDF

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks for the interesting reference. The problem is 3d - the dependency on the axial variable is in the boundary conditions. Another problem is that I would need to generalise the solution for more than one inner circle. I updated the question to add these details.

Comment: So, the cylinders are not infinite in extent?

Comment: @Dr.MV The cylinders are infinite but the potential decays towards  for z-> +/- infinity.

Comment: Will you not separate the $z$ component in Laplace's equation, rendering the remaining problem 2-D?

Comment: You're right, I guess I could do that. But how about generalising for more than one inner circles?